# How to hide Content Editor WebPart which has InfoPath form link in it based on condition

Tags: infopath

I am using SharePoint 2010 and my scenario is I have created an InfoPath form and form link is being set up in Content Editor WebPart to directly open to submit a form for the first time. Everything working fine, now I am in need to hide the link once a form is submitted on the page.

Can any one suggest me how to approach on this or if anyone has snippets that would resolve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking of alternative way, this solution will not remove the link but when the user tries again, he will be redirected to a view in InfoPath saying that he already submitted a form.

What you can do is get the current user logged in when opening the InfoPath then create a Data connection to your library to query the Created By field. Now on form load, find a match. If the rule found a match, the form will redirect the user to a view saying that he already submitted a form.

Comment: hi Mekalikot thanks for the suggestion but am looking to hide the webpart once they submit the form it depends on the date if the date is today than they should not see the link to the form